# Error in Implementing levelplot in R for a Categorical Raster with RAT

Tags: raster, r, levelplot

I have a raster in .tif format which I am trying to visualize in R using levelplot. Here is what I have done so far:

```
library(raster)
library(lattice)

data_tif <- raster("fthrt14_21.tif", RAT = TRUE)
data_tif

rat <- read.dbf("fthrt14_21.tif.vat.dbf")
rat
data_tif <- ratify(data_tif)
colnames(rat)[1] <- "ID"
levels(data_tif) <- rat


levelplot(data_tif, col.regions=rev(terrain.colors(5)),main = "Fire Threats"
          , attr(THRT_CLASS))
```

I am getting an error: Error in UseMethod("levelplot") : no applicable method for 'levelplot' applied to an object of class "c('RasterLayer', 'Raster', 'BasicRaster')"

How can I resolve this error? This is what my RAT looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the levelplot function to plot a raster, you need to install the "rasterVis" package first.

Answer (score 0):

Its got nothing to do with the raster being categorical - there is no `levelplot` function for any type of raster in the `raster` or `lattice` packages:

```
> library(raster)
> library(lattice)
> r = raster(matrix(runif(100),10,10))
> levelplot(r)
Error in UseMethod("levelplot") : 
  no applicable method for 'levelplot' applied to an object of class "c('RasterLayer', 'Raster', 'BasicRaster')"
```